# Docker and Cinder, is it possible in openstack?

Tags: docker, device, openstack, loopback

Is it possible to mount Cinder volumes on docker containers in openstack?

And if it is, is there a way to encrypt data leaving the container to the cinder volume?

I was thinking of mounting the volume as a loopback device and encrypt the data as it was being flushed to the disk. Ist this possible?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to mount Cinder volumes inside a Docker container in OpenStack.

A fundamental problem is that Docker is filesystem-based, rather than block-device-based.  Any block device -- like a Cinder volume -- would need to be formatted with a filesystem and mounted prior to starting the container.  While it might be technically feasible, the necessary support for this does not yet exist.

The [Manila](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Manila) project may be a better solution for adding storage to containers, but I haven't looked into that and I don't know if (a) the project works at all yet and (b) it it works with nova-docker.

If you're not using the nova-docker driver but are instead using the Heat plugin for Docker, you can mount host volumes in a container similar to `docker run -v ...`, but making this work seamlessly across multiple nodes in a multi-tenant setting may be difficult or impossible.